# Having trouble debugging iOS app on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xamarin

I am trying to test an app I created for the iPhone but I am having issues testing it on my device. I created the provisioning profile and the million other steps it requires to complete such a simple task but I am getting the following error:

```
-debugtrack -monodevelop-port 10000 -connection-mode usberror MT1107: Application failed to launch
```

I tried creating a test application on my Xcode and was unable to do so either and got the following error message:

```
Could not launch “test” NotFound
```

Answer (score 5):

You may need to click on the app manually on your device, at which time you might get a dialog about "Untrusted App Developer". Once I clicked "Trust" the app was able to launch.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I had to restart my iPhone once I loaded the provisioning profile.